# where is my program looking for functions

Tags: c-preprocessor, point-cloud-library, triangulation

I'm working with pcl library and I'm calling a function that I'm not sure where it is defined. I don't know what version of pcl I have so I don't know if the Documentation I'm looking at online is correct for me. I thought I knew where it was but I added a print statement in the function and nothing came up.

The code I'm trying to run is:

pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation gp3;
    pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;

```
// Set the maximum distance between connected points (maximum edge length)
gp3.setSearchRadius (0.025);

// Set typical values for the parameters
gp3.setMu (2.5);
gp3.setMaximumNearestNeighbors (100);
gp3.setMaximumSurfaceAngle(M_PI/4); // 45 degrees
gp3.setMinimumAngle(M_PI/18); // 10 degrees
gp3.setMaximumAngle(2*M_PI/3); // 120 degrees
gp3.setNormalConsistency(false);


// Get result
gp3.setInputCloud (cloud_with_normals);
gp3.setSearchMethod (tree2);
gp3.reconstruct (triangles);
```

I'm looking for reconstruct and thought it was in

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/surface/impl/reconstruction.hpp
```

but when I added a print statement nothing came up in main.

I ran locate on reconstruction.hpp and added a print statement to each reconstruct function and none of them printed in main.

the result of locate reconstruction.hpp | less was:

```
/home/cs4752/.local/share/Trash/files/perception (copy)/pcl/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/reconstruction.hpp

/home/cs4752/Desktop/perception/pcl/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/reconstruction.hpp

/home/cs4752/perception/pcl/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/reconstruction.hpp

/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/surface/impl/reconstruction.hpp
```

I cloned project from github a couple times by accident, but if I checked all of them I would think that wasn't the problem.